# jQuery object get value by key

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you get the value of `assocIMG` by key matching the key eg

if I have a var `11786` I want it to return `media/catalog/product/8795139_633.jpg`

```
var spConfig = {
    "attributes": {
        "125": {
            "id": "125",
            "code": "pos_colours",
            "label": "Colour",
            "options": [{
                "id": "236",
                "label": "Dazzling Blue",
                "price": "0",
                "oldPrice": "0",
                "products": ["11148"]
            }, {
                "id": "305",
                "label": "Vintage Brown",
                "price": "0",
                "oldPrice": "0",
                "products": ["11786", "11787", "11788", "11789", "11790", "11791", "11792", "11793"]
            }]
        }

    }
};
var assocIMG = // Added  - Removed { here, causes issues with other scripts when not working with a configurable product.
    {
        11786: 'media/catalog/product/8795139_633.jpg',
        11787: 'media/catalog/product/8795139_633.jpg',
    }
```

Above is the objects I am working with and below is my current jQuery. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$('#attribute125').change(function() {
    var image = $(this).val();

    $.each(spConfig.attributes, function() {

        prods = $(this.options).filter( function() { return this.id == image; } )[0].products[0];

    alert(prods);

    });

});
```

Comment: Can you explain better? I'm confused: you have a lot of product ids in that products array, but only 2 images?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to get object members by their keys. You have the variable `prods` containing a string (`"11786"`), and the object `assocIMG` with various keys. Then just use

```
assocIMG[prods]
```

to get the property value `'media/catalog/product/8795139_633.jpg'` which is associated with that key.

Note that you should always use strings as keys in your object literal, IE does not support numbers there:

```
var assocIMG = {
    "11786": 'media/catalog/product/8795139_633.jpg',
    "11787": 'media/catalog/product/8795139_633.jpg'
};
```

---

Another improvement to your script would be not to loop through the `spConfig.attributes` each time, and potentially execute your action multiple times if an image is contained in more than one attribute. Instead, build a hash object out of it, where you can just look up the respective product id.

```
var productById = {};
$.each(spConfig.attributes, function() {
    $.each(this.options, function() {
         var id = this.id;
         productsById[i] = this.products[0];
    });
});

$('#attribute').change(function() {
    var id = this.value;
    var prod = productById[id];
    var image = assocIMG[prod];
    $("#product_img").attr("src", image);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not use numbers as object keys (in their start). If you want to get the value associated with the `11786` integer key, you will need to use this syntax:

```
assocIMG["11786"] or assocIMG[11786]
```

**Not**

```
assocIMG.11786
```

The first thing that you need to do is to create your keys as strings, since you would have:

```
var assocIMG = {
    "11786": 'media/catalog/product/8795139_633.jpg',
    "11787": 'media/catalog/product/8795139_633.jpg',
}
```

But even doing this, you won't be able to access the field using `assocIMG.11786` and the first valid sintax that I presented will still work. The correct approach would be:

```
var assocIMG = {
    id11786: 'media/catalog/product/8795139_633.jpg',
    id11787: 'media/catalog/product/8795139_633.jpg',
}
```

Or

```
var assocIMG = {
    "id11786": 'media/catalog/product/8795139_633.jpg',
    "id11787": 'media/catalog/product/8795139_633.jpg',
}
```

Note that the keys are now starting with letters, not numbers. And now, you will can access the `11786` field as `assocIMG.id11786` or `assocIMG["id11786"]`, **not** `assocIMG[id11786]`

Comment: Numbers are valid javascript object literal keys, only IE does not support that. However, when written as strings there is no reason not to use them.

Answer (score 1):

To Get the Value from object by matching key I ended up with the following

```
$.each(assocIMG, function(index, value) { 
        if(index == prods) {
             var image_path = value;
             $("#product_img").attr("src", image_path);
             //alert(image_path); 
        }
```

Comment: @Bergi Could you please explain why it is wrong? Thx

Comment: There's no reason to enumerate the object just to access a specific, already-known key. Just like you wouldn't iterate an array only to access its *i*th index.